# How do I create a search bar for Google Drive folder in my JS app?

Tags: reactjs, google-drive-api, searchbar

I'm building a site that renders content saved in my Google Drive.
I used this template to embed a specific folder from Drive:

```
<iframe src="https://drive.google.com/embeddedfolderview?id=FOLDER-ID#grid" width="100%" height="600px" border="0"></iframe>
```

It works great! But I want to add a search bar to my site, so the user will be able to search for content inside of this embedded folder.
Is that possible? If so, how?

Here's the whole code (using ReactJs):

```
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
import '../App.css'

export function SampleVideos() {
    const history = useHistory()
    const moveToComponent= (componentRoute) =>{
        history.push(`/${componentRoute}`)
     }


    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Sample Videos</h1>
            <iframe src="https://drive.google.com/embeddedfolderview?id=FOLDER-ID#grid" width="100%" height="600px" border="0"></iframe>

            
            <footer>
                Can't watch the videos?
                <span className="href-span" onClick = {()=>moveToComponent('VideoSupport')}>Click Here</span>
            </footer>
       </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Hi there @DrorYair ! If you want a search bar in Drive, please take a look at [File Picker](https://developers.google.com/picker/docs). You can tune it to adopt its search function. Don't hesitate to give it a test and write back to me with your findings or question.

Comment: hi  @Jacques-GuzelHeron I tried the google picker, but : a. I couldn't find the option to only provide a search-bar to the users, and b. the Google Picker required a list of users which will be able to access this service, and asks them for access permissions to their own account. I would appreciate it if you could share with how you think I can implement this.

Comment: Reading your comment I understand that you want anyone to access the search bar. If my understanding is correct, then please check this [Google Support](https://support.google.com/sites/thread/7489142) thread and its many solutions.

Comment: As an alternative, you could use [Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list) to list your whole folder at once and let the users navigate it. As another option, you could flesh out that last option building a formularie that asks the user for the `corpora` parameter to later request it to the Drive API. Please, test these fixes and share back your findings.